# Making a custom CSS per mobile

Tags: css, mobile

I have a wordpress site and everything looks the way it should on a regular browser. But now if i go to it in mobile it it there are certain sections that don't look right. Is there a way to modify the css when mobile or tablet connect or how do i fix the mobile version of it?

Comment: Use media queries http://google.com/search?q=css+media+queries ( [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp) )

Answer (score 0):

You need use the `wp_is_mobile()`

For example changing your `style.css` in the `header.php`

```
<?php
if ( wp_is_mobile() ) {
    /* Display and echo mobile specific stuff here */
}
?>
```

Comment: Just note, `wp_is_mobile()` might be "useful", it is unreliable and should not be trusted. You are better off using media queries

Comment: yes but wordpress is versatile, you can change all css screen only with media query but combining the two ways your site is under your control.